# Paraphrase Generation - state-of-the-art?

Tags: nlp, text-generation

I need to paraphrase short, but abstract sentences, such as:

> He prefers variety to routine.

or

> I am easily discouraged.

I've played around couple of online tools (such as https://quillbot.com/) just to get a feeling for how well this particular task is solved by available models and was quite disappointed. Hence my question:

**What is current state-of-the-art in paraphrase generation?**

Comment: possible duplicate : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/65864/nlp-variations-of-a-text-without-modifying-its-meaning